# Have a regular expression keep matching as much as possible?

Tags: regex, perl

Is there a convenient way to write a regex that will try to match as much of the *regex* as possible?

Example:

```
my $re = qr/a ([a-z]+) (\d+)/;

match_longest($re, "a") => ()
match_longest($re, "a word") => ("word")
match_longest($re, "a word 123") => ("word", "123")
match_longest($re, "a 123") => ()
```

That is, `$re` is considered to be a sequence of regular expressions, and `match_longest` attempts to match as much of this sequence. In a sense, matching never fails - it's only a question of how much matching succeeded. Once a regex match fails, `undef` for the parts that didn't match.

I know I could write a function which takes a sequence of regexes and creates a single regex to do the job of `match_longest`. Here's an outline of the idea:

Suppose you have three regexes: `$r1`, `$r2` and `$r3`. The single regex to perform the job of `match_longest` would have the following structure:

```
$r = ($r1 $r2 $r3)? | $r1 ($r2 $r3) | $r1 $r2 $r3?
```

Unfortunately, this is quadratic in the number of regexes. Is it possible to be more efficient?

Comment: changed the example regex since `123` matches `\w+`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the regex

```
$r = ($r1 ($r2 ($r3)?)?)?
```

which has each regex contained only once. You may also use non-capturing groups `(?:...)` in this example to not interfere with your original regular expressions.

Comment: This will only correctly capture the parts when there is a trailing space present.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, using nested groups with `?` should work:

```
my $re = qr/a ((\w+) (\d+)?)?/;
```

Comment: This regex doesn't fully match `a word`.

Answer (score 0):

This particular case can be written like this:

```
m/a (?:(\w+)(?: (\d+))?)?/
```